# AS2: Conflict between mouse events on a symbol and child symbol

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, scaleform

I can't seem to setup mouse events (onRelease/onRollOver/...) on both a symbol and its child symbols.

I have a `m_Background` symbol, which contains two non-overlapping rectangles, lets say `m_Left` and `m_Right` and the following code within my class for the object containing the `m_Background` symbol (rest of the code is pretty much empty and functions called just contain a trace to check what is being called)

```
class MyComponent extends UIComponent
{
    var m_Background:MovieClip;

    function configUI()
    {
        m_Background.m_Left.onPress = Delegate.create(this, Function1);
        m_Background.onRollOver = Delegate.create(this, Function2);
        m_Background.onRollOut = Delegate.create(this, Function3);
    }
}
```

With that code, the `onRollOver` and `onRollOut` events trigger fine but onPress doesn't. And if I comment out the last 2 lines, onPress starts working again. Also the order of declaration doesn't seem to matter and onPress always ends up overwritten (because it's on a child element I assume?)

Any suggestions on how to solve that conflict to have all events work as expected on nested symbols?

Comment: It's a very old AS2 problem - the parent is capturing ALL mouse events once you assign any mouse event listeners to it. Take a look here, there are a few solutions to that problem: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/buttoncapturing/

Comment: Thanks, that article was quite helpful and that "event bubbling" looks like a great way to work around it!